# MEMOIR CLASS - Problems with "ELL" chapter-style

Tags: memoir, chapters

As a new LaTex user I decided (don't ask me why) to jump straight in the Memoir Class. Don't get me wrong, I've had some classes to teach me how to use LaTeX.

That said While I'm getting a bit more comfortable with the Class and its options, I still get constant error messages since I decided to use the "ell" chapter style

> Here's the code of the chapterstyle as found in the file : " **memoir.dtx**" :
>
> `\makechapterstyle{ell}{%
>     \chapterstyle{default}
>     \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily}
>     \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
>     \settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
>     % \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
>     %   \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
>     %   \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
>     %   \hrulefill
>     %   \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
>     %   \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
>     \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
>       % \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
>       % \hfill
>       % \raisebox{10mm}[0pt][0pt]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
>       %                           \hspace*{1em}
>       % \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-3.0\onelineskip}
>       \chs**@ell@helper**{\thechapter}%
>     }
>     \renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
>       \chs**@ell@helper**{}\afterchapternum}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
>       %\vskip\onelineskip
>       \raggedleft {\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak}}`

but this code does give buggy results...:

[image]

The @ell@helper is found in the code (I bolded it)

Now,

there is the code as I modified it and as I use it actually and that's when i get the aforementioned errors :

> Here's the code of the ELL chapterstylle as I use it :
>
> `\makechapterstyle{ell}{%
>     \chapterstyle{default}
>     \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily}
>     \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
>     \settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
>      \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
>       \vspace*{.0mm}{\beforechapskip}%
>       \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
>       \hrulefill
>        \smash{\rule{0.2mm}{13mm}}
>       \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
>     \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
>      \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
>        \hfill
>       \raisebox{8,5mm}[0mm][0mm]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
>                                 \hspace*{1em}
>        \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-2.5\onelineskip}
>       %\chs@ell@helper{\thechapter}%
>     }
>     \renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
>       \chs{}\afterchapternum}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
>       \vskip\onelineskip
>       \raggedleft {\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak}}`

And here are the results I get :

[image]

This is how it is supposed to look like when we check the memoir class chapter styles.

That said I get constant "missing number, treated as zero" and " illegal unit of mesure (pt inserted)" errors whenever I create a chapter...

I've tried to figure it out by myself but am actually at a loss.

Like some may have said elsewhere, it doesn't prevent the document to generate correctly but it's still annoying and I would have liked to find a clear solution to this. If it can help, I'll now paste my full preamble :

> My full preamble with my modified version of the ELL chapterstyle code :
>
> %-----(BEGIN PREAMBLE)-----%
>
> `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt ,twoside ,openright ,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
>   \raggedbottom
>   %[twoside] est utilisé pour indiquer que le document sera imprimé recto-verso.%
>   %[openright] est utilisé pour indiquer que tout nouveau chapitre doit commencer sur un recto.%
>   %[extrafontsizes] est utilisé pour permettre, si l'on veut, le recours à des tailles de polices d'écritures dépassant les 25pt.`
>
> %-----( BEGIN PACKAGEs)-----%
>
> `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %obligatoire%
>   \usepackage[french]{babel}
>   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
>   \usepackage{xcolor}%pour surligner du texte (la commande en cours de frappe est  : \colorbox{couleur}{texte  à surligner}%
>   \usepackage{soulutf8} %la commande pour surligner est : \texthl{texte à surligner}
>   \usepackage{ulem}`
>
> %-----(BEGIN MACRO)-----%
>
> %enclenche le style de chapitre utilisé (pour d'autres exemples compatibles, voir "the memoir class (2018) p.385 et sq.)
>
> `\newcommand*{\sclabel}[1]{\normalfont\scshape #1} %à voir si je conserve, permet de personnaliser les étiquettes des items des listes...`
>
> `\OnehalfSpacing %interligne 1,5`
>
> %-----CHAPTER STYLE "ELL" (BEGIN)-----%
>
> `\makechapterstyle{ell}{%
>     \chapterstyle{default}
>     \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily}
>     \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
>     \settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
>      \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
>       \vspace*{.0mm}{\beforechapskip}%
>       \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
>       \hrulefill
>        \smash{\rule{0.2mm}{13mm}}
>       \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
>     \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
>      \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
>        \hfill
>       \raisebox{8,5mm}[0mm][0mm]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
>                                 \hspace*{1em}
>        \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-2.5\onelineskip}
>       %\chs@ell@helper{\thechapter}%
>     }
>     \renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
>       \chs{}\afterchapternum}
>     \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
>       \vskip\onelineskip
>       \raggedleft {\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak}}`
>
> %-----CHAPTER STYLE "ELL" (END)-------%

\chapterstyle{ell}%à placer après la section ci-dessus qui reparamètre certains aspects du "chapterstyle ELL". Si on place la commande avant, elle chargera la configuration d'origine au lieu de prendre encompte les modifications ci-dessus.

> `\setsecnumdepth{section}%indique à partir de quel niveau de titre on numérote
>    \maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}%indique jusqu'à quel niveau de titre on numérote`
>
> `\setlength{\headheight}{15.5pt}`
>
> %-----(END MACRO)-----%
>
> %------(END PREAMBLE)------%`

Sorry for the very long post,

And thank you for any help you will be able to provide me

:-)

Regards,

Elrad

Comment: Please make your examples into full self contained documents, that makes them much much easier to test. Also you might want to learn the proper method for displaying code in the cite, indent all the code lines by four spaces, then they will be nicely formatted (in the editor on the website you can mark the code and then press CTRL-k to have the marked text indented)

Comment: From the messy code you are presenting it is not clear at all what you are doing. Since `ell` is build in, why are you copying the code? And if you're copying the code, remember `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around it to get macros with `@` in their name to work

Comment: Hello,

First of all thank you for both your answers, I'm sorry i didn't take the time to properly learn how to post on this website before actually posting code. I take your comments in consideration and will proceed as you say in a cleaner and more practical way. Thank you !

And thank you for making remembering me about \makealetter /makeaother I had totally skipped that part. I'll test it.

Comment: Edit : another thing, @daleif   you say my code is messy, how can I improve its structure/ presentation (in my own editor) so it can be more readable and clear ? Thank you !

Comment: What I'm saying is that the code you present here is not something others can work work with. Note that almost 100% of the time ask for a full (but minimal) example that can be copied and tested as is. Your code here is just an assortment of sniplets. I have no idea what you are trying to do with this code, so I've never tested it.

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with the editor on this site, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help, for code examples should have each line indented by four spaces (there is a keyboard shortcut for that)